# Why does Thread.Abort lock things up for 60+ seconds

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, serial-port, thread-safety

I want to present the user with a list of COM ports that are available for my program to communicate on and not already open by other programs.  To do this, I loop through all COM ports and attempt to open each one.  I add the ones that I can open successfully to a list.

That process was taking 60+ seconds.  It only takes 1/2 second on each available port to open it, but the unavailable ports take a while before the Open function fails.  I don't want to have the user wait that long for each COM port that I check.

So, I put the 'ValidateSerialPort' function on a thread and I Abort that thread if it hasn't completed within 1/2 second.

The problem is that the Thread.Abort() command sometimes locks up for 60+ seconds.

Can somebody tell me why it locks up?  Or, can somebody show me a super fast way to see which COM ports are available for me to Open?  I'm using C# with .net on a Windows 10 machine.

Here is my code:

```
    private static bool _portIsValid;

    private static void ValidateSerialPort(object portName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var port = new SerialPort(portName?.ToString()))
            {
                port.Open();
                _portIsValid = port.IsOpen;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {// ignore, don't care
        }
    }
```

The above method is called by the code snip below, but **thread.Abort()** sometimes locks up for 60+ seconds:

```
...
...
            var possiblePorts = new List<string>();

            foreach (var port in ports)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(port))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var thread = new Thread(ValidateSerialPort);
                _portIsValid = false;
                thread.Start(port);
                SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => _portIsValid, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
                thread.Abort();
                if (_portIsValid)
                {
                    possiblePorts.Add(port);
                }
            }
...
...
```

Comment: In short dont abort threads unless you are prepared to tear down your appdomain, its just not safe. There is always a better way

Comment: Does the [`SerialPort.ReadTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readtimeout) property has any effect on the delay caused by the `Open` method, for non-existent ports?